# Number of matrices with positive determinant whose entries are {1,-1}

Tags: combinatorics, matrices, determinant

> How many different matrices  $3 \times 3$ matrix, whose every entry is 1 or -1, have positive determinant?

My approach:
I found out the possible values of determinant of all such $3 \times 3$ matrices whose entires are 1 or -1: {-4,-2,0,2,4}.

The number of matrices with positive determinant = number of matrices with negative determinant by symmetry, (as we can just multiply each entry with -1, and sign of determinant would change as it's an odd degree).

So the answer would be $\frac{2^9-n(0)}{2}$ where n(0) is the number of singular matrices(determinant 0).

For n(0), any two rows/columns must be proportional to each other i.e. all 1 or all -1 or one of them 1 and the other -1.(4 possibilities for two such choosen rows/columns).

So I tried to count it as follows:
$({3 \choose 2} \cdot 4 \cdot 2^3)\cdot 2=192$ for rows and columns. However this includes cases with three rows /three column repeated as well, for which we must subtract the over counted cases. 
For all 3 rows/columns to be proportional there are $(3\cdot 2 +2) \cdot 2 = 16$ ways of which each is counted thrice.
So a total of 48 repeated cases.

So n(0)=192-48=144.

This gives number of matrices with positive determinant as $\frac{512-144}{2}=184$, 
However the answer is given as $96$.

Where am I going wrong?

Also is there a more systematic way of doing this question?

Comment: "any two rows/columns must be proportional to each other" not necessary, there just have to be a (non-trivial) linear combination equal to $0$, it's a more relaxed condition.

Comment: @Alexey Burdin Oh yes! Is there another way to proceed? I think counting all such cases is getting really cumbersome

Comment: You have only $8$ vectors so there's only ${8\choose 2}$ ways to select a space, spanned by the first $2$ of the $3$ vectors... yet too long...

Comment: Btw, how did you arrive at a determinant, being $2$? I can't see any. You can [check the code](https://tio.run/##XY/NasMwEITvfoq9FOSyCVHcOonBpz6G0EF11o2M/pBkSJ7eld0USvcysLOzfBMe@eZdcw5xWbQNPmbQmWL23qTqubAq36oxeguDN4aGrL1L8DQ//OxKoLpS7o2yn1cF9y7NlrEdBz2COCDHBo/4hu9SOPlyBDKJgNev6999iP7K7sJKMUkYfQSLE2gH5GZLUWViuq43w6H@Z/yC7gNFO2e1gbGo3BcxQ47d63UqlVI5hELIhOAFpZEoCg62RU94Rn6Wsu773fFUhahdZhWUeTZjW06LQ1diWjRdu0rbXUpm49qomNEps@lnsxX4Q1cqzkN5suPIJUYKpHJ/WdHqZfkG) if familiar with python

Comment: @Alexey Burdin yes you are correct. I miscalculated one possibility sorry for that

Comment: When you flip all six, nothing changes.  So when you flip a subset, you get the same result as flipping all the others instead.

Comment: @Empy2 Thank you I just realised that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For counting the singular cases, here's a geometric interpretation . . .

Consider the solid cube $C=\big{\{}(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3\mid x,y,z\in [-1,1]\big\}$.

Let $S$ be the set of $3{\,\times\,}3$ matrices with all entries in $\{\pm 1\}$.

For $A\in S$ we can regard the $3$ rows of $A$ as vertices $V_1,V_2,V_3$ of $C$, hence $\det(A)=0$ if and only if the vectors $\vec{V_1},\vec{V_2},\vec{V_3}$ are coplanar.

To count the number of matrices $A\in S$ such that $\det(A)=0$, consider $3$ cases . . .

**Case $(1)$:**$\;V_1,V_2,V_3$ are all equal.

  The count for this case is
  $8$
  .

**Case $(2)$:**$\;$Exactly two of $V_1,V_2,V_3$ are all equal.

  The count for this case is
  $8{\,\cdot\,}7{\,\cdot\,}3=168$
  , since there
  $8$
  choices for the vertex with multiplicity
  $2$
  ,
  $7$
  choices for the non-duplicated vertex, and
  $3$
  ways of arranging the rows of
  $A$
  .

**Case $(3)$:**$\;\vec{V_1},\vec{V_2},\vec{V_3}$ are coplanar and $V_1,V_2,V_3$ are distinct.

  Then the plane containing the triangle with vertices
  $V_1,V_2,V_3$
  must pass through the origin. There are
  $6$
  such planes, each of which passes through two diagonally opposite edges of
  $C$
  . Each such plane contains
  $4$
  vertices of
  $C$
  , so for each such plane there are
  $4$
  choices for
  $\{V_1,V_2,V_3\}$
  . Thus there are
  $6{\,\cdot\,}4=24$
  possible choices for
  $\{V_1,V_2,V_3\}$
  , and for each such choice there are
  $3!=6$
  was of arranging the rows of
  $A$
  . Hence the count for this case is
  $24{\,\cdot\,}6=144$
  .

Summing the counts for the $3$ cases, we get a total count of $8+168+144=320$ for the count of the number of singular matrices.

Hence we get ${\Large{\frac{2^9-320}{2}}}=96$ for the count of the number of matrices $A\in S$ with $\det(A) > 0$.

Comment: Wow that's very nice! Thanks a lot!